# Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{}: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: in loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[/mnt/asec/com.-1/pkg.apk

Tags: android, classnotfoundexception

I have one application which is run on ADT 12 completely without any error, i have upgrade ADT from 12 to ADT 20. But after upgrading ADT i had run my application but it throws below error,

> 08-06 20:12:53.896: E/AndroidRuntime(13958): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>   08-06 20:12:53.896: E/AndroidRuntime(13958): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.aruhat.mobileapps.funforkids/com.aruhat.mobileapps.kidszoo.LearnWithFunGame}: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.aruhat.mobileapps.kidszoo.LearnWithFunGame in loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[/mnt/asec/com.aruhat.mobileapps.funforkids-1/pkg.apk]
>   08-06 20:12:53.896: E/AndroidRuntime(13958):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2585)
>   08-06 20:12:53.896: E/AndroidRuntime(13958):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2679)
>   08-06 20:12:53.896: E/AndroidRuntime(13958):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2300(ActivityThread.java:125)
>   08-06 20:12:53.896: E/AndroidRuntime(13958):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2033)
>   08-06 20:12:53.896: E/AndroidRuntime(13958):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
>   08-06 20:12:53.896: E/AndroidRuntime(13958):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
>   08-06 20:12:53.896: E/AndroidRuntime(13958):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
>   08-06 20:12:53.896: E/AndroidRuntime(13958):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
>   08-06 20:12:53.896: E/AndroidRuntime(13958):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
>   08-06 20:12:53.896: E/AndroidRuntime(13958):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
>   08-06 20:12:53.896: E/AndroidRuntime(13958):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
>   08-06 20:12:53.896: E/AndroidRuntime(13958):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
>   08-06 20:12:53.896: E/AndroidRuntime(13958): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.aruhat.mobileapps.kidszoo.LearnWithFunGame in loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[/mnt/asec/com.aruhat.mobileapps.funforkids-1/pkg.apk]
>   08-06 20:12:53.896: E/AndroidRuntime(13958):    at dalvik.system.PathClassLoader.findClass(PathClassLoader.java:243)
>   08-06 20:12:53.896: E/AndroidRuntime(13958):    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:573)
>   08-06 20:12:53.896: E/AndroidRuntime(13958):    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:532)
>   08-06 20:12:53.896: E/AndroidRuntime(13958):    at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1021)
>   08-06 20:12:53.896: E/AndroidRuntime(13958):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2577)
>   08-06 20:12:53.896: E/AndroidRuntime(13958):    ... 11 more

But i have these class in my manifest. I had searchout so many answer but no one help to solveout this. Pls give some usefull solution of this problem.

Thanks...!!!

Comment: Well, there are a lot of thing that could cause this error. So, are you extending that class to an `Activity`? Are you sure there is no conflict with package names?

Answer (score 1):

I fixed this error when I update "Android SDK Tools" and "Android SDK Platform-tools"

Answer (score 0):

Right click on project-> click properties->remove android dependency.Again right click on project click on android tools and click fix project properties. It should work.